# Google Visualization API clickable chart-items

Tags: google-visualization

I am using GV-API to publish a piechart with information on my website. De items published are not clickable by default, but I thought I found a way in their documentation (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter)

Implementation as follows:

```
<div id="chart_{!! $id !!}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({!!json_encode($data)!!});
var options = {!! json_encode($options) !!};
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('<a href="/{1}">{0}</a>');
formatter.format(data, [0, 1]);
var material = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_{!! $id !!}'));
material.draw(data, options);
});
```

And indeed this enforces a kind of formatting, but unfortunately the information is shown as plain text, not as a clickable URL. It is a bit weird, since this is almost the same as the example in the documentation.

I searched the web for solutions, but most of them refer to deprecated API's.

Any help appreciated

Comment: it appears the pattern formatter only works on a [Table chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information